# First order ordinary differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Please tell how one can identify 1st order

1) Homogeneous differential equations.

2) Homogeneous linear differential equations.

3) Non Homogeneous differential equations.

4) Non Homogeneous linear differential equations.

Comment: First-order simply means that no derivatives higher than the first appears. For an ordinary differential equation, this just means that the equation can be written in the form $F(x, y(x), y'(x)) = 0$ for some function $F$.

Comment: sorry. i now mentioned ordinary differential equations.

Comment: Homogeneous means zero is a solution. Linear means that if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions, $ay_1+by_2$ is two ($a,b$ being constants).

Answer (score 0):

- First-order means the highest degree of derivative with respect to $y$ is one. That is, we only have $y'$ or $\frac{dy}{dx}$. No $y'', y'''$, etc.
- Linear means that the differential equation is of the form $A(x)y'+B(x)y+C(x)=0$. That is, there is no $y^2,yy',(y')^2,$ etc.
- Homogeneous means that in the above form also $C(x)=0$. So the general form of a first-order linear homogeneous equation is $y'+P(x)y=0$